# Window not displaying text from file

Tags: java

I am trying to have a window open and have it display the text from a file.  However when I run it, I simply get a blank window.  Here is the code for the window - I get no errors from eclipse at all.

```
package presentation;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import domain.Items;
import services.exceptions.ItemNotFoundException;
import services.itemservice.*;

public class ShowAllInventory extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4498395613773129897L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ShowAllInventory frame = new ShowAllInventory();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the window frame.
     */
    public ShowAllInventory() throws ItemNotFoundException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        /**
         * Load the inventory
         */

        IItemsService service = new ItemsServiceImpl();
        try {
            Items items = service.getItems();
        } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println ("Items Not Found");
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the code for the interface the code is calling -

```
    public Items getItems () throws ItemNotFoundException;

}
```

And here is the implementation...

```
/**
 * Getting Items from the database
 * @return 
 * @throws ItemNotFoundException
 */
@Override
public Items getItems() throws ItemNotFoundException {

    Items items = (Items) null;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream input = new
                ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream("itemdatabase"));
        items = (Items)input.readObject();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println ("IOException");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return items;       
}
```

Comment: new FileInputStream("item database") where is the file extension?

Comment: Why catch the exceptions and then just keep going? Why not let the exceptions bubble up? Just dumping exceptions to `System.out` is a sure-fire way to end up missing them...

Comment: heavens where is your window, aaach sorry I vote to close this question

Comment: I didn't think about not having a file extension, but would that cause the blank window? The output works just fine without a file extension, but I will add one and see if that helps.  I didn't write that part of the code so I don't know what the rational for not having an extension was. ** nope, adding the file extension did not help.

Comment: in which line is the content supposed to be set? i don't see the connection between your file handling and your Swing stuff

Comment: I think I see what you mean, the code is there to call the text document, but never to place it in a swing element - correct?  Can you give me an idea where to look to figure out how to put that set of code into a swing element?

Comment: use [JTextArea#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Post your entire (relevant) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if your `IItemsService` can load the file properly. But most likely you get a blank window because in your code, I think you forgot to add a component to display the items. If your `Items` works as a `List`. You can use a `JList` to display them.

```
Item[] items = ...// use your Items to populate Item to an array
JList itemList = new JList(items);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(itemList);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100)); //put your preferred size here

contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

IMHO, I think you should not throw `ItemNotFoundException` since finding no items should be a normal case. `FileNotFoundException` should be the one to be thrown here.

---

**UPDATED**
If you want to use `JTextField` or `JTextArea` you have to something like this:

```
...
Items items = service.getItems();
...

String itemContent = items.toString(); // you have to put meaningful information from class Items to this String
JTextArea itemDisplay = new JTextArea(itemContent);
// JTextField itemDisplay = new JTextField(itemContent);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100)); //put your preferred size here

contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: just one problem - one "new JList(items);" I get an error that "The constructor JList(Items) is undefined"

Comment: the constructor of `JList` require you to supply a array of elements. You have to create an array of items, not passing your `Items`.

Comment: would it be easier to do this as just a text box?

Comment: Sure you can use other component to display your item. My assumption is that your `Items` is a wrapper class for a collection of item (like `List`). If you just want to display text, feel free to use `JTextArea` or other components.

Comment: any idea why I get the same constructor error if I try this?          JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(items);
        getContentPane().add(textField1);

Comment: ahhh - I see, this is starting to make a lot more sense to me now. Thank you.